# Getting: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /view.jsp(35,3) PWC6117: File "/assignment/entry_search_columns.jspf" not found

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, jsp-fragments

The problem is:

> javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /view.jsp(35,3) PWC6117: File "/assignment/entry_search_columns.jspf" not found

I am trying to build the gradebook application by watching the tutorials from passport.liferay.com which is not available right now. I have created the **entry_search_columns.jspf** where I am having several errors saying that entry cannot be resolved and row cannot be resolved for these errors after building the whole application I am not able to solve the problem.

Here is the code with these errors are below:

```
<%-- Generate assignment view URL. --%>
<portlet:renderURL var="viewAssignmentURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcRenderCommandName"
        value="<%=MVCCommandNames.VIEW_ASSIGNMENT%>" />
    <portlet:param name="redirect" value="${currentURL}" />
    <portlet:param name="assignmentId" value="${entry.assignmentId}" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<c:choose>
    <%-- Descriptive (list) view --%>
    <c:when
        test='${assignmentsManagementToolbarDisplayContext.getDisplayStyle().equals("descriptive")}'>
        <%-- User --%>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-user showDetails="<%=false%>"
            userId="<%=entry.getUserId()%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text colspan="<%=2%>">
            <%
                String modifiedDateDescription = LanguageUtil.getTimeDescription(request,
                                    System.currentTimeMillis() - entry.getModifiedDate().getTime(), true);
            %>
            <h5 class="text-default">
                <liferay-ui:message
                    arguments="<%=new String[] { entry.getUserName(), modifiedDateDescription }%>"
                    key="x-modified-x-ago" />
            </h5>
            <h4>
                <aui:a href="${viewAssignmentURL}">
 ${entry.getTitle(locale)}
 </aui:a>
            </h4>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
            path="/assignment/entry_actions.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <%-- Card view --%>
    <c:when
        test='${assignmentsManagementToolbarDisplayContext.getDisplayStyle().equals("icon")}'>
        <%
            row.setCssClass("lfr-asset-item");
        %>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
            <%-- Vertical card. --%>
            <liferay-frontend:icon-vertical-card
                actionJsp="/assignment/entry_actions.jsp"
                actionJspServletContext="<%= application %>" icon="cards2"
                resultRow="${row}" title="${entry.getTitle(locale)}"
                url="${viewAssignmentURL}">
                <liferay-frontend:vertical-card-sticker-bottom>

                    <liferay-ui:user-portrait cssClass="sticker sticker-bottom"
                        userId="${entry.userId}" />
                </liferay-frontend:vertical-card-sticker-bottom>
                <liferay-frontend:vertical-card-footer>

                    <div class="truncate-text">

                        <%-- Strip HTML --%>

                        <%=HtmlUtil.stripHtml(entry.getDescription())%>
                    </div>
                </liferay-frontend:vertical-card-footer>
            </liferay-frontend:icon-vertical-card>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
    </c:when>
    <%-- Table view --%>
    <c:otherwise>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text href="${viewAssignmentURL}"
            name="title" value="<%= entry.getTitle(locale) %>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-user name="author"
            userId="${entry.userId}" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-date name="create-date"
            property="createDate" />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp name="actions"
            path="/assignment/entry_actions.jsp" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I have done all the codes and make all arrangements to make my project because of this jspf file I failed to implement this.

Comment: Please clarify: Your question title mentions `entry_search_columns.jspf" not found`, while your code sample doesn't contain a reference to this jsp fragment.

Comment: how can I clarify that can you help please?

Comment: First: please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824). Then: we'd need a [mcve]. You're asking about a missing file, so the next step would be to let us know _if_ you have that file, _where_ it _is_ and where it's included from (file and its location)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the errors in this entry_search_columns.jspf file, the libraries are imported in the init.jsp file and included in view.jsp.
The problem is with the tomcat server version, you must use the bundle compatible with your workspace project version 7.3-ga1, for example for this course you must use tomcat-9.0.37. This is the official liferay bundle with tomcat-9.0.37 "[liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.5-ga6- 20200930172312275](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/releases?expanded=true&page=9)".
Here you can see the latest version "[liferay-portal-releases](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/releases)".
Of course this is the community version, if you use the commercial version you can generate a bundle automatically.